# VScode regex replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a long country list, within has more than 1200 countries,
and i want to replace

```
        e164_cc: '250',
        iso2_cc: 'RW',
        display_name: 'Rwanda (RW) [+250]'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '590',
        iso2_cc: 'BL',
        display_name: 'Saint Barthélemy (BL) [+590]'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '290',
        iso2_cc: 'SH',
        display_name: 'Saint Helena (SH) [+290]'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '1',
        iso2_cc: 'KN',
        display_name: 'St. Kitts (KN) [+1]'
    },
```

into

```
         e164_cc: '250',
        iso2_cc: 'RW',
        display_name: 'Rwanda'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '590',
        iso2_cc: 'BL',
        display_name: 'Saint Barthélemy'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '290',
        iso2_cc: 'SH',
        display_name: 'Saint Helena'
    },
    {
        e164_cc: '1',
        iso2_cc: 'KN',
        display_name: 'St. Kitts'
    },
```

by removing everything like  (KN) [+1], which is

space + (KN) + space + [+1]

so how could i do that?

Updated:

At first i just typed \s([^']*

Now i know i also need to add parentheses.

Comment: That's a single edit on the file. Why can't you just do it manually using VS Code as a text editor?

Comment: Or a simple text find and replace, without the regex? It's a simple substitution of a single string. The find expression would be ` (KN) [+`' , and the replace expression would be nothing.

Comment: Find: `(\s\([^']*)` replace with nothing.  Assumes the country code, etc. changes with each entry.

Comment: Better to do a search and replace in VSCode itself and search for the first open bracket, get the remaining length from the first open bracket to the end of the string (display_name) and then just trim the string.

Comment: Please avoid the impression of only phrasing requirements and asking for implementation. Demosntrate some own effort. E.g. by describing what you tried, what your closest attempt is, its result and how it is different from what you want. That clarifies how much you know about using regex in your specific environment. Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment:

Find: `(\s*\([^']*)`  space then `(`, then everything up to closing `'`.

Replace: with nothing

Answer (score 1):

Do a "Replace" (Ctrl + H), and use this Regex as the "Find" (enable Regular Expression, Alt + R):

```
 \(\w+\) \[\+\d+\]
```

And put nothing in the "Replace" field.

Then, hit "Replace All".

Explanation: This regex matches exactly the parts that you want to delete, so you just replace those parts with nothing.